# Variable's value is not changed in setup()

Tags: java, junit, android-testing

I am developing a test class for my application. I have 3 tests and based on the test method, I want to have different setups. Here is what my code looks like:

```
`public class MainActivityTest extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    int counter = 0;

    public MainActivityTest(Class<MainActivity> name) {
        super(name);

    }

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        switch (counter) {
        case 0:
            //do setup 1
            break;
        case 1:
            //do setup 2
            break;
        case 2:
            //do setup 3
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }

    public void testTest1() {
        //do test 1
        assertEquals(1, counter);
    }

    public void testTest2() {
        //do test 2
        assertEquals(2, counter);
    }

    public void testTest3() {
        //do test 3
        assertEquals(3, counter);

    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }`
```

As is said in documentations, setup method is called per test. The problem is that testTest2 and testTest3 fail because counter's value is 1 in both of them. I supposed it would be incremented every time setup is called.

Comment: Regardless of whether you get this working, this doesn't look right to me. The setup function is for doing the common setup for the following tests; if it needs to be this different for each one, there's not really that much benefit in using it, it might be better to break things up.

Comment: ^^^ Alex is correct. Also, you cannot be sure your tests will be run in the order you want, so perhaps they would all fail anyway on their `assertEquals` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your counter variable static, the tests will pass.

Each test gets its own instance of the test class and thus the counter value is re-initialized to the starting value of zero with every test.